# Issue Retrieving JSON Content from URL in PHP with Curl

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to retrieve the price values from this [url](https://www.speedway.com/Pages/GasPriceSearch.aspx?lat=40.4172871&lng=-82.90712300000001&st=ohio).

I can see the content when inspecting the price element in Firefox and it seems to be using json. Here's what I've been trying with curl in php.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HEADER, 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.speedway.com/Pages/GasPriceSearch.aspx?lat=40.4172871&lng=-82.90712300000001&st=ohio'
]);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump(json_decode($resp));
```

The result I always receive from this is `NULL` so it doesn't seem that I'm getting any json content in return.

I have tried setting a useragent and that doesn't change anything. I also thought that maybe the server is preventing me from receiving what I want. I tried adding

```
$http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

and outputting the result of that, but I got a `200` so I don't think that's an issue either. If I just `echo $resp` I receive all the HTML content, but the json data isn't in there.

I'm no expert to what I'm trying to do, so I'm sure I'm missing something, but not sure what. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you provided is the webpage itself, not the JSON data. The JavaScript in that page *loads* the JSON data from somewhere else, specifically, from here:

```
https://www.speedway.com/_layouts/Speedway/GasPrices.aspx?lat=40.4172871&lng=-82.90712300000001&st=ohio
```

Use that instead, and your code should retrieve the correct data.

Comment: How did you get that URL? But you are definitely right. Thanks!

Comment: @user2951249 I used Chrome's Network tab in the web inspector to see what AJAX requests the page was making.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error.

```
CURLOPT_HEADER, 1,
```

should be

```
CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
```

or just remove it completely, because it isn't required.

But the web address you're getting the data from isn't a JSON page anyway.

Comment: My bad. Changing code a lot. But I removed it. It didn't affect what I was trying to do though. Wrong URL is what fixed the issue as you're last statement says. Alexis posted first and gave me the correct URL. Thanks, though.